# ArcGIS 10 Add-ins - How to adjust the size of an add-in toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in

I've built an add-in toolbar with two buttons.  Works great, but I'd like to make the toolbar a little wider so that the user can see it's full caption. Is there a property I can adjust in the Config.esriaddinx file to force the toolbar to be wider? Or do I have to make each of my button images wider?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set the toolbar width using a property as the toolbars resize automatically to fit their contents. You could add a ComboBox, set it to disabled and if needed set its width using the `sizeString` attribute in the .esriaddinx file -- a bit tacky. There are built-in toolbars that have this problem as well (e.g. Globe View Tools in ArcCatalog), so it seems ESRI felt it to not be a big enough deal to do anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button images in toolbar commands are limited to 16x16 pixel so you won't be able to change the size of the toolbar that way.
Command buttons don't display the caption in Add-ins. If you hover they show the tip in a popup and the message in the ArcMap message bar, but otherwise just the image is shown. 
However, if the command in nested in a menu then it will show the image and caption. 
If you are referring to the title bar of an undocked toolbar then there is nothing you can do except add 'dummy' space to your toolbar with a disabled menu,combobox,etc.